# sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-core:3.0.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Facing below issue:

> Extracting structure failed, reason: structure file is empty stack
> trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output stack trace
> is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
> (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading
> org.apache.spark:spark-core:3.0.1 Not found Not found not found:
> C:\Users\admin.ivy2\localorg.apache.spark\spark-core\3.0.1\ivys\ivy.xml
> not found:
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core/3.0.1/spark-core-3.0.1.pom
> (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error
> downloading org.apache.spark:spark-core:3.0.1 Not found Not found not
> found:
> C:\Users\admin.ivy2\localorg.apache.spark\spark-core\3.0.1\ivys\ivy.xml
> not found:
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core/3.0.1/spark-core-3.0.1.pom
> Total time: 2 s, completed 14 Sep, 2021 6:16:34 PM

**spark version : 3.0.1**

buid.sbt file

```
name := "OCH_SCALA"

version := "0.3"
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "3.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %"spark-sql" % "3.0.1" % provided"
```

Comment: Change the scala version to 2.12.0

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your build definition:

1. You should use the `%%` syntax so that the Scala version is automatically used when looking for dependency
2. Use Scala 2.12, Spark is not available for Scala 2.13+ yet.

That is:

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.12.13"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.1" % Provided
```