# Encounter sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-14

I am fairly new to scala & sbt and encountered an issue when attempting to compile my scala project and have 1 hypothesis as to why i am seeing the below error:

1. the path to the dependency on my local is configured wrongly. it is currently: "/Users/jutay/.ivy2/localorg.apache.spark/....." and there should be a "/" after "local" which should make the path look like ".../.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/..."

But I am unsure if this is truly the case?

As i did some research and found the following online examples, which is showing that those who encountered the same sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException have the similar path designed e.g. ".../.ivy2/localnet.cakesolutions/..." so it seems that the missing "/" in the path is not the one causing the problem?

but in the event that this is indeed the one causing the problem, where can i make the config change to add a "/" after the string "local"?

- https://users.scala-lang.org/t/help-with-this-package-downloading-error/8257
- [sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-core:3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69178224/sbt-librarymanagement-resolveexception-error-downloading-org-apache-sparkspark)

If there is no issue with the path above and it is correct and expected, what am i currently doing wrong or missing leading sbt compile to fail with the above error? It seems to not be able to download this dependency:

Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-corcle_2.12:3.3.0

Note: I am currently using intelliJ to work on this scala sbt project.

I am kind of stuck on this issue.

`[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last update for the full output [error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-corcle_2.12:3.3.0 [error]   Not found [error]   Not found [error]   not found: /Users/jutay/.ivy2/localorg.apache.spark/spark-corcle_2.12/3.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml [error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-corcle_2.12/3.3.0/spark-corcle_2.12-3.3.0.pom [error] Total time: 2 s, completed 28 Nov, 2022 5:27:51 PM`

This is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "proj123"

version := "3.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-corcle" % "3.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.0",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.4",
  "com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies" % "0.26.0" % "provided",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.2",
  "com.jcraft" % "jsch" % "0.1.55",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-web" % "5.3.18",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.4.15",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.13",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.9"
)
```

I have tried looking up possible solutions online via google related to `sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException` but i did not found any solution that would be helpful.

I tried checking my .bash_profile and my sbtconfig.txt as to whether there are any config options there to edit the path (by adding a "/") as a possible way to try and resolve the issue, but there seems to be no such options.

This is my .bash_profile :

```
# Configuration for node to trust the xxxx Proxy Certificates
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/xxxx_proxy_cacerts.pem'

# Configuration to load nvm - node version manager
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm

# >>> coursier install directory >>>
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/jutay/Documents/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export SBT_HOME=/Users/jutay/Downloads/sbt
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:/$JAVA_HOME/bin:/$SBT_HOME/bin:$PATH
# <<< coursier install directory <<<
```

and this is the sbtconfig.txt inside the sbt folder which my .bash_profile reference:

```
# sbt configuration file for Windows

# Set the java args

#-mem 1024 was added in sbt.bat as default

#-Xms1024m
#-Xmx1024m
#-Xss4M
#-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m

# Set the extra sbt options

# -Dsbt.log.format=true
```

Comment: I suspect that you're not supposed to configure Ivy. So actually your issue is the dependency `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-corcle" % "3.3.0"`. Where did you get it? Maven Search doesn't know it https://search.maven.org/search?q=spark-corcle Google doesn't either https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spark-corcle%22+apache

Comment: Shouldn't it be `spark-core`?